# Components not appearing on my formPanel

Tags: java, swing

I've a formPanel which extends JPanel and is centered directly on a MainFrame that extends JFrame.

```
// this is the constructor of the mainframe

public MainFrame() {
    super("Invoice Generator");

    toolBar=new ToolBar();
    formPanel=new FormPanel();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(formPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


// this is where i add the custom components

 setBackground(new Color(170, 175, 255));


        setVisible(true);
        layout();
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
    }



public void layout() {

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    /////////////first row/////////////////////////////
    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=0;
    gc.weightx=1;
    gc.weighty=1;
    gc.insets=new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    add(new JButton("Booked by"), gc);

    gc.gridx=1;
    gc.gridy=0;
    gc.weightx=1;
    gc.weighty=1;
    gc.insets=new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    add(text1, gc);

}
```

My components are not appearing on my formPanel, why?

Comment: You changed the layout for one and you're adding your components to the frame, not the `formPanel`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

Your `layout` method seems to be operating on your `JFrame` and not your `formPanel`

Something like...

```
public void layout() {

    formPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    /////////////first row/////////////////////////////
    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=0;
    gc.weightx=1;
    gc.weighty=1;
    gc.insets=new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    formPanel.add(new JButton("Booked by"), gc);

    gc.gridx=1;
    gc.gridy=0;
    gc.weightx=1;
    gc.weighty=1;
    gc.insets=new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    formPanel.add(text1, gc);

}
```

might work better.

I'd be tempered to create a custom class which extends from `JPanel` which the encapsulates these fields and then simply add it to the frame instead.